# Create User on Mongodb ad C# driver

Tags: c#, database, mongodb

Hi everyone I wanted to ask what is the best way to create a new user who has read and write privileges on a specific database.
I am trying with this but it doesn't work

```C#
var command = new BsonDocument
            {
                {"createUser", Mail.Text },
                {"pwd", Password.Text },
                {"roles", new BsonArray()
                    {
                        new BsonDocument
                        {
                            {"role", "readWrite"},
                            {"db", DenSociale.Text }
                        }
                    } 
                }
            };
            await db.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>(command);
```

return this error

> MongoError: not authorized on (User) to execute command { createUser: "newuser", pwd: "xxx", roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "User" } ], lsid: { id: UUID("ce6c39d4-e14c-4f6c-b5d0-d66d210e9833") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1622456008, 30), signature: { hash: BinData(0, F02EF0CAD605D9ECBCF3E928F84853FECE9B2829), keyId: 6968352101504122883 } }, $db: "(User)" }

Comment: Please only add related tags to your question. Yes, you might be developing a Xamarin app, but that doesn't change the content of your question or the answer because the question isn't related to the Xamarin portion of your program. Also, the Visual Studio tag is only for questions about the Visual Studio application, not code you author with it.

Comment: Please explain what "but it doesn't work" means.

Comment: update return this error ----- MongoError: not authorized on (User) to execute command { createUser: "newuser", pwd: "xxx", roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "User" } ], lsid: { id: UUID("ce6c39d4-e14c-4f6c-b5d0-d66d210e9833") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1622456008, 30), signature: { hash: BinData(0, F02EF0CAD605D9ECBCF3E928F84853FECE9B2829), keyId: 6968352101504122883 } }, $db: "(User)" }

Comment: See this Stack Exchange post with similar issue: [for mongo, not able to create users other than admin with error command createUser requires authentication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/292514/for-mongo-not-able-to-create-users-other-than-admin-with-error-command-createus)

Comment: It seems the user you have connected to the database with does not have permissions to create other users.  Can you access an account with elevated permissions and try again?